# parar la lectura de una palabra (python)

Tags: python, array, lista, bucles, automatafinito

Estoy programando un automata con transiciones de (estado,simbolo,estado)
estados, estado inicial, estados finales, alfabeto, transiciones y la palabra a leer estan guardadas por `

```
dic = {
"estados": input().split(),
"alf":input().split(),
"q0": input(),
"qF": input().split(),
"transiciones": input().split(),
"palabra":input(),}
```

`Y para leer las transiciones y hacerlas las tengo como:`

```
def trn():
estado_actual = dic["q0"]
for n in dic["transiciones"]:
    for x in dic["palabra"]:
        dic["transiciones"] = n.strip("()").split(",")
        if estado_actual == dic["transiciones"][0]:
            if x == dic["transiciones"][1]:
                estado_actual = dic["transiciones"][2]
                print(dic["palabra"],estado_actual)
            elif dic["transiciones"][1] == "#":
                estado_actual = dic["transiciones"][2]
                print(dic["palabra"],estado_actual)
if estado_actual in dic["qF"]:
    print("Aceptada")
else:
    print('Rechazada')`
```

El problema es que palabras invalidas siguen el bucle hasta aceptarlas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui por ejemplo los estados son A B C, simbolos son 0 1, estado inicial A, Final C, las transiciones son (A,0,A) (A,1,B) (B,1,C) y la palabra a leer es 0001, con esta palabra el estado final deberia ser de B y la palabra deberia ser rechazada pero sigue hasta llegar a C y por eso queda aceptada.

Probe con poner un len(dic["palabra"]) para que no siga pero me invalida ahi la cadena entonces no se que hacer

Comment: Con esta línea `dic["transiciones"] = n.strip("()").split(",")` destruyes el contenido inicial de la entrada. La reemplazas con `['A', '0', 'A']`.

Comment: Entiendo que reemplazo el contenido inicial pero necesito el strip y el split para poder leer las transiciones

Comment: Mejor preparar el diccionario antes de entrar a procesar.

Answer (score 0):

**Problemas**

En la línea

```
dic["transiciones"] = n.strip("()").split(",")
```

estas reemplazado la lista de transiciones:

```
['(A,0,A)', '(A,1,B)', '(B,1,C)']
```

con

```
['A', '0', 'A']
```

lo que genera caos.

Hay otras cosas que tampoco están claras en tu algoritmo, pero no creo que valga la pena discutirlas

Una solución más simple es esta:

```
def trn(estado_inicial, estado_final, palabra):
    #   Revisar si llegamos al destino al acabarse la palabra
    if not palabra:
        return estado_inicial == estado_final

    #   Buscar en las transiciones una que calce con este estado+letra
    #   alternativas es una lista de transiciones validas en este estado y letra
    alternativas = [trans for trans in dic["transiciones"] if trans[0] == estado_inicial and trans[1] == palabra[0]]
    #   Recorrer la lista de alternativas y ver si alguna lleva a destino
    for alt in alternativas:
        if trn(alt[2], estado_final, palabra[1:]):
            return True
    #   Ninguna alternativa lleva a destino
    return False
```

Esta función recursiva chequea si es posible ir del estado inicial al estado final usando la palabra (completa).

La función primero chequea la condición de término: si la palabra está vacía, sólo queda revisar si el estado inicial es el estado final deseado. Retornar `True` en caso de éxito.

Si todavía queda palabra, extraer la primera letra y luego recorrer las transiciones seleccionando las que comiencen en el estado actual y acepten la letra en cuestión.

Si la lista está vacia, por aquí no hay solución.

Si la lista tiene elementos, probar cada uno para ver si alguno lleva a la solución. Para esto se invoca la función recursivamente pasando como estado inicial el estado destino que nos da la transición, y pasando la palabra recortada en su primera posición.

#### Demo

```
dic = {
"estados": ["A", "B", "C"],
"alf": ["0", "1"],
"q0": "A",
"qF": "C",
"transiciones": [["A","0","A"], ["A","1","B"], ["B","1","C"]],
"palabra": "0001"}

def trn(estado_inicial, estado_final, palabra):
    #   Revisar si llegamos al destino al acabarse la palabra
    if not palabra:
        return estado_inicial == estado_final

    #   Buscar en las transiciones una que calce con este estado+letra
    #   alternativas es una lista de transiciones validas en este estado y letra
    alternativas = [trans for trans in dic["transiciones"] if trans[0] == estado_inicial and trans[1] == palabra[0]]
    #   Recorrer la lista de alternativas y ver si alguna lleva a destino
    for alt in alternativas:
        if trn(alt[2], estado_final, palabra[1:]):
            return True
    #   Ninguna alternativa lleva a destino
    return False


tests = [
    "011",
    "0001",
    "00011"
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, end=" ")
    if trn("A", "C", test):
        print("Aceptada")
    else:
        print('Rechazada')
```

produce:

```
011 Aceptada
0001 Rechazada
00011 Aceptada

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda pero desgraciadamente deben ser por consola todos los datos, por eso usaba el ' dic["transiciones"] = n.strip("()").split(",")' para limpiar los () y separar las comas,

Comment: @lollmao Siempre puedes cambiar la parte de pedir los datos ...

Comment: Lo comprendo pero sin el strip y el split los datos no me quedan separados en estado,simbolo,estado

Comment: @lollmao. Tienes que preparar los datos antes de llamar a la función. Dividir para reinar.